# How to remove MBR Rootkits/bootkits?

Tags: malware, rootkits

How do I remove them from internal hard drives and USB sticks? Can they infect MicroSD cards as well or anything else? DVD? cd?

Heard it's possible to do with a live CD via formatting. What are best methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out, The following command from the Linux terminal window as root will erase the mbr

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
This will erase the first sector (512 bytes) of the hard drive /dev/sda . 
Be sure that this is the right drive to erase!  So, keep your external backup drive disconnected, to avoid any bad error.

To erase anything before the (former) first partition of the drive, located at the 1st MiB, you can erase 2048 sectors: 
This is for the case a virus used that area to store any info.

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=2048

So only the second command is necessary.

The only GUI way to delete the mbr would be to make a new partition table. This affects the master boot sector only. However, because there was such a virus history, it is safer to clean a few more, not just the mbr.

Still doesn't delete the Volume Boot Record, which can also be infected.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a tool that can clean your MBR, like [Boot Repair Disk](https://alternativeto.net/software/boot-repair/). Make sure to wipe the MBR, and not repair it, as generally you can't know if the malware would be removed by repairing.

I guess it is fair to assume that if you have a writable MBR, it could be infected. Thus, yes, an attacker could infect MicroSD cards. DVD/CD (optical drives) function differently (see [UDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) and [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)), they do not use a MBR.

For the creation of a Live CD, it's best to use [dedicated software](https://alternativeto.net/software/etcher/) as it takes care of different variations, be it hardware/firmware or configuration, such as OS or partitioning.

So, if you need to make sure you have removed any possible malware on the drive:

1. Create a clean MBR, practically redoing the partitioning of the drive.
2. Format your new partition(s).

Both steps are necessary, because these are two logically different steps and generally doing one does not affect the other.

Comment: So any tools that are boot repair, or mbr repair should all restore an infected mbr to a clean state without the infection still present? i thought they were for fixing it if it was corrupt not working ect, i guess they are. Is it possible they could repair and not successfully remove the rootkit it manages to stick around?

Comment: I thought dvd cd wouldn't be possible, as i was thinking no mbr, poster below said it's possible to put it on cd dvd, getting confused now, yeah good tip i already have live usbs ect that software looks good tho, writting iso to microsd cards, i'm thinking if formatting due to virus infections smart idea would be to always fix repair the mbr before reinstalling the os. Assuming you just wanted to remove the mbr create a new one and not repair is formatting the drive the best course of action?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify: to ensure that the MBR is clean, I would completely wipe and rewrite it anew. It's difficult to say if just repairing is going to catch all possible manipulations.

Comment: Notice that @Paul's response to CD, DVD or BIOS does not make explicit reference to MBR. So while they would be vulnerable in general, this cannot happen via MBR, as it is absent.

Comment: As for best course of action, I'd suggest wiping MBR first and then creating your partitions. This should reset anything writable on the drive. I've updated my answer with these clarifications.

Comment: Cleaning the MBR is only the first half. The code in the MBR usually just loads some code from a partition and this code will still be there.

Comment: That's ok, how do i wipe the MBR? and create a clean one? the tool you linked to mentions only about repairing. @Paul's recommendation is to simply use any software that offers to format a hard drive. Gparted Windows Install disk they both let you do that. Problem is this page https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/rootkit/ under What to do if you have a BIOS/Hardware level rootkit it suggests you have to zero the drive to remove the bootkit, always mentions format won't always delete data probably because it doesn't zero

Comment: This type of rootkit boots up at the same time as your operating system, by infecting the master boot record (MBR) or the volume boot record (VBR). So do i need to delete the mbr and vbr are they the same thing? does that partition table get deleted when the mbr is deleted? i'm still confused. i thought these where meant to be hard to remove, just clicking format seems pretty simple.

Comment: They also make that sound like MBR and VBR are both similar but two different methods of infection for malware do i need to remove both?

Comment: In `gparted` cleaning the MBR [is equivalent](https://superuser.com/questions/700770/mbr-equals-msdos-for-gparted) to writing a partition table with an `msdos` file system.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record), MBR is part of the VBR on partitioned devices.

Comment: Yeah i've seen that before, so if i use any software and write a partition table on the drive i want to clean, in doing so it will remove the old partition table and create the new one, as well as removing the master boot record and volume boot record at the same time? so that should be 100% clean no chance of infection to mbr or vbr? by clean i assume you mean it deletes it and makes a new fresh copy? cleaning is what your tool does i think?

Comment: I found this https://www.lifewire.com/volume-boot-record-2625818 apparently formatting will create a new vbr each partition has it's own vbr and the mbr or bios loads the vbr i'm lost so if i create a mbr partition table msdos then install linux does that mean i don't have a mbr anymore and now it's simply grub? and if i was using UEFI and windows it would be the GPT instead of mbr then? https://www.disk-partition.com/articles/remove-mbr-partition-3889i.html

Comment: Your original question was about MBR. Now you are all over the place. Please clarify the question, so that we understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I confused myself, i worked out what confused me tho. Yes i still want to no how to delete the mbr which i believe the vbr is also involved as either can be infected with a bootkit so both need to be removed.

Comment: I did find this https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/erase-your-mbr/ so as paul said maybe just formatting with any tool achieves what they said to remove the mbr and partition table don't understand volume boot record tho.

Comment: Your approach would be different, depending on whether you have multiple partitions on a device, or not. If you format a partition, you don't touch your MBR. If your fromatting deletes the partition table, then you have also done both of the operations that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Obviously if you had multiple partitions, you would delete them first. Then choose the only one left and click format on it? so your saying clicking format on on a drive provided it's not multiple partitions it will recreate the mbr the same way you could do it buy creating a new partition table msdos on gparted assume format deletes the partition table in this case. Kinda confused how you said to create a new mbr then format partitions, so create partitions then click format on them? i usually don't have partitions just one main one click format on that?

Comment: Would this work as well? https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/erase-your-mbr/ i assume you would need the option for format both the partition table and mbr i don't think the option just the mbr alone would work?

Answer (score 0):

All you'll need to do is boot up a LiveCD or Windows installation or whatever OS you prefer and format both USB and HDD that will resolve a typical rootkit.

Rootkit is just for hiding particular malware but yes it can infect any form media such as MicroSD, USB, CD, DVD, BIOS and so on. It can get more complex by infecting routers by re-writing the firmware on there. Ofcourse, extremely rare and would have to be programmed for that particularly version of the router. BIOS is also another rare rootkit.

Some good reading articles for you:

[Bad USB](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/code-published-for-unfixable-usb-attack/)

[Bad USB - Solution](https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/badusb-exploit-vulnerability-fix/)

[Rootkit](https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/rootkit/)

Comment: So basically just open gparted click and any drive click format and that's it? when i wasn't sure i found looked this up.

Comment: To format just your MBR

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1

Note the blocksize of 446 is supposed to erase everything up to your partition table, but not your partition table itself.

To format (remove) your MBR & partition table

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1

To format (remove) the 1st MB located before the MBR

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=2048

Comment: So does simply choosing to reformat with any tool delete the mbr and partition table, then recreate it? by typical i assume you mean a "bootkit" interesting i didn't no there was a solution for badusb i was aware of it tho.

Comment: I think CD and DVD can't be infected as the poster above suggested no mbr to infect.

Comment: Also just saw the infection can infect either the mbr or the vbr there two different things that need to be fixed are they? do you no if bootkits effect android iphones as well?